# Determine if an IEnumerable<T> contains any object of another IEnumerable<T>

Tags: .net, ienumerable

I have 2 `IEnumerable<int>`

```
IEnumerable<int> x;
IEnumerable<int> y;
```

What is the best best way to determine if any int in y is present in the x?
Currently I'm using:

```
return x.Intersect<int>(y).Count() > 0;
```

Would it be significantly faster to loop through and test each individually?

```
foreach (int i in x)
{
    foreach (int j in y)
    {
        if (i == j) return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

The lists are relatively light, with not more than 50 ints in x and 4 in y if that matters in the consideration.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It would be fastest to use the [`Any` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) instead of the [`Count` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357758.aspx):

```
return x.Intersect<int>(y).Any();
```

This assumes that the [`IEnumerable<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) implementation doesn't also implement [`ICollection<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx).  In that case, `Count` (in the case where `IEnumerable<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`) is an O(N) operation while `Any` is *always* an O(1) operation.  (as it only checks for a *single* element). However, the behavior of `Count` is an implementation detail, and you shouldn't rely on that.

I've written about this more in-depth [in a blog post](http://www.caspershouse.com/post/Anything-Counts.aspx) that goes into detail about when to use `Count()` vs. `Any()`.  In summary:

- **DO** use `Enumerable.Any` extension method to check for the existence of elements in the sequence.
- **DO NOT** use `Enumerable.Count` extension method in comparisons against zero, as the following are semantically equivalent:

  - `sequence.Count() == 0`
  - `!sequence.Any()`
- **DO NOT** use the `Enumerable.Count` extension method in comparisons against the “not zero” condition, as the following are semantically equivalent:

  - `sequence.Count != 0`
  - `sequence.Any()`

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: The original answer below is really dealing in terms of complexity. If the sequences are short enough, all the calls through `GetNext()`, building a `HashSet` etc will actually be more expensive than using `Intersect(y).Any()`. However, in that case both calls will be really pretty quick anyway.

In other words, `Intersect(y).Any()` definitely scales better as the two sequences get longer, but for if you're absolutely *sure* that the sequences are short, the nested loop solution will be faster.

**Original answer**

No, `Intersect()` will be faster than the two-loop solution - but as CasperOne wrote, `Any()` will be faster than `Count()` because it will exit as soon as it sees an element.

Assuming sequences of length N and M, Intersect will be `O(N + M)` whereas the two-loop solution is `O(N * M)`.

Intersect builds up a `HashSet` from the "inner" sequence (this takes `O(M)` complexity) and then loops through the outer sequence (which takes `O(N)` complexity), yielding any element which is in the set. These results are streamed - the inner sequence will be evaluated when the first element is requested from `Intersect()`, but this only goes as far as finding the first match (if any). Using `Any()` you'll have an "early out" if there are any matches, so we don't need to take the overall number of matches into consideration when working out the complexity.

Streaming results from LINQ rocks - it's well worth getting your head round (as well as deferred execution).

Comment: Without me starting my profiler, could you explain why? Seems the two loops would cost less than the count?

Answer (score 3):

`Intersect` is okay, but as others have said I wouldn't call `.Count()` on the result.

The reason is that Intersect does *not* create the intersection of the two lists. It creates an `IEnumerable` that is *capable* of *enumerating* that intersection, but it doesn't actually enumerate those results yet.  Most of the work is deferred until the time when you finally iterate over this enumeration.

The problem with `Count` is that it does iterate over the entire enumeration.  So not only does it always count all the results, but it causes all of the work involved in computing those results to run as well.

Calling `Any` instead will be *very* fast by comparison, because you will compute *at most* one intersection result before returning.  Of course, in the case where there are no matches it will still need to iterate the entire list.  However, that's no worse off than you were before.  In fact, it's still faster because as Jon Skeet mentioned, the `Intersect` function uses a HashSet to compute the results rather than iterating over everything.  Your best and average cases are improved tremendously.

It's like the difference between these two snippets:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (int i in x)
{
   foreach (int j in y)
   {
      if (i==j) count++;
   }
}
return (count > 0);
```

.

```
// this one should look familiar
foreach (int i in x)
{
    foreach (int j in y)
    {
       if (i==j) return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Obviously the 2nd is much faster on average.  The performance of `Any()` would be *analogous* (not the same as, thanks to the HashSet) the 2nd snippet, while `Count()` would be analogous to the first.

Answer (score 1):

You're better of doing this:

```
return x.Intersect(y).Any();
```

This will abort as soon as it finds a single match, and stop enumerating through the collections.

Comment: Wouldn't it do the intersect first, then check if there was any element?

Comment: @Josh: No, due to streaming the results.

Comment: Josh: Look in MSDN for "Deferred Execution" in LINQ.  It's worth taking the time to understand how and why it works, and how you can use it to your advantage.

Comment: @Reed: It's not deferred execution as such - it's streaming the results. They're somewhat different. For instance, OrderBy is deferred but as soon as it's asked for the first result it has to process *all* of it. It then yields the results one by one, of course. Intersect is half stream half buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This question and last answer are more than 1 yr old as of my answer; however, my findings differ from the accepted answer. I find that looping is significantly faster than using Intersect.Any(). Maybe my benchmark code isn't right?

Here's the code I used to find the number of iterations per second between Intersect, nested loops, and a loop with IndexOf. Please excuse the VB. ;)

```
Dim ArrayLength As Integer = 50
Dim doesContain As Boolean = False
Dim counter As Integer = 0
Dim sw As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
Dim BigArray1 As String() = New String(ArrayLength) {}
Dim BigArray2 As String() = New String(ArrayLength) {}
Dim rand As New Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
For i As Integer = 0 To ArrayLength
    BigArray1(i) = Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(0, 255)).ToString()
    BigArray2(i) = Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(0, 255)).ToString()
Next
Dim AnEnumerable1 As IEnumerable(Of String) = BigArray1
Dim AnEnumerable2 As IEnumerable(Of String) = BigArray2

counter = 0
sw.Restart()
Do
    doesContain = False
    For Each x As String In AnEnumerable1
        For Each y As String In AnEnumerable2
            If x.Equals(y) Then
                doesContain = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If doesContain Then Exit For
    Next
    counter += 1
Loop While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000
Console.WriteLine("InnerLoop iterated:  " & counter.ToString() & " times in " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() & "ms.")

counter = 0
sw.Restart()
Do
    doesContain = AnEnumerable1.Intersect(AnEnumerable2).Any()
    counter += 1
Loop While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000
Console.WriteLine("Intersect iterated:  " & counter.ToString() & " times in " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() & "ms.")

counter = 0
sw.Restart()
Do
    For Each x As String In AnEnumerable1
        If Array.IndexOf(Of String)(BigArray2, x) <> -1 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    counter += 1
Loop While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000
Console.WriteLine("IndexOf iterated:    " & counter.ToString() & " times in " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() & "ms.")
```

My results over two 5,000,000 item arrays. Higher iterations are better:

- InnerLoop iterated:     2974553 times in        1000ms.
- Intersect iterated:     4 times in      1168ms.
- **IndexOf iterated:       4194423 times in        1000ms.**

My results over two 50 item arrays. Higher iterations are better:

- InnerLoop iterated:     375712 times in 1000ms.
- Intersect iterated:     203721 times in 1000ms.
- **IndexOf iterated:       668421 times in 1000ms.**

Comment: I just noticed that if I tweak probability of matching items in both arrays then the performance of Intersect jumps significantly. The less chance for an early match makes Intersect considerably faster.

Comment: A huge issue with this is that you're iterating through one of the enumerables multiple times; regardless of the performance impact, you could have unintended side-effects (what if it was backed by a database call?).