# Is ConcurrentDictionary.Count > 0 the same as ConcurrentDictionary.Any()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, concurrentdictionary

If I have a
[`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2)
instance, does it matter whether I use the `Count` property or LINQ's `Any()`?  I'd rather write `dict.Any()` instead of `dict.Count > 0` as I think `Any()` is more descriptive.

I'm only concerned about correctness, not performance; use case is:

```
void f()
{
   if (concurrentDictionary.Count <= 0) // or !Any() ?
      return; // dictionary is empty, nothing to do
   
   // ...
}
```

Comment: The question is why you are dealing with `Any` or  `Count` in the first place. Those will give you a snapshot value which may, by the very nature of the whole situation, be void in the next instant. If you need a snapshot of the contents of the dictionary, use the `.ToArray` method of it, then you can analyze the contents of that.

Comment: In any case, it depends on what you define "the same as" in this context. Does it execute the same code? No.

Comment: Semantically, yes, they are the same.  Performance wise, no, it is not guaranteed.  You should always use `Any()` for the best performance.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/691155/50776

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the `Count` nor the `Any()`. To correct API to use is the [`IsEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.isempty) property:

```
// Gets a value that indicates whether the ConcurrentDictionary is empty.
public bool IsEmpty { get; }
```

Compared to the `Any()` it doesn't cause the allocation of an enumerator, and gives a more reliable answer. The behavior of the `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` enumerator is [pretty loosely documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getenumerator). For example [it's not guaranteed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46374) that a single enumeration of the dictionary will return unique keys. It could be said that even if the enumerator never returned any elements, it wouldn't violate any specs.

Compared to the `Count` it doesn't acquire the internal locks, unless the dictionary is empty. So the only scenario that the `IsEmpty` could cause contention, is if you have a bunch of worker threads that are doing nothing else than invoking the `IsEmpty` in a tight loop on an empty dictionary.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs#L1479) of the `IsEmpty` property (.NET 8), in case you want to see it:

```
public bool IsEmpty
{
    get
    {
        // Check if any buckets are non-empty, without acquiring any locks.
        // This fast path should generally suffice as collections are usually not empty.
        if (!AreAllBucketsEmpty())
        {
            return false;
        }

        // We didn't see any buckets containing items, however we can't be sure
        // the collection was actually empty at any point in time as items may have been
        // added and removed while iterating over the buckets such that we never saw an
        // empty bucket, but there was always an item present in at least one bucket.
        int locksAcquired = 0;
        try
        {
            AcquireAllLocks(ref locksAcquired);

            return AreAllBucketsEmpty();
        }
        finally
        {
            ReleaseLocks(locksAcquired);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The question [Are IEnumerable Linq methods thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103779/are-ienumerable-linq-methods-thread-safe) addresses the fact that the IEnumerable methods on LINQ queries are not thread safe without a specific lock being kept protecting the collection.

You can look at the [reference code for ConcurrentDictionary](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,b2dcb93f9ede4ba0) to see that the enumerator does not provide a thread-safe snapshot. Additional the MSDN Documentation for [ConcurrentDictionary.GetEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287131%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> The enumerator returned from the dictionary is safe to use concurrently with reads and writes to the dictionary, however it does not represent a moment-in-time snapshot of the dictionary. The contents exposed through the enumerator may contain modifications made to the dictionary after GetEnumerator was called

The Count property takes a full lock on the dictionary and returns a consistent result.

So depending on whether you want to take a lock on the dictionary to run `Any()` it is probably cleaner to check for `Count > 0`.

Comment: wrong: [ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.GetEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287131%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): *The enumerator returned from the dictionary **is safe to use concurrently with reads and writes to the dictionary**, however it does not represent a moment-in-time snapshot of the dictionary. The contents exposed through the enumerator may contain modifications made to the dictionary after GetEnumerator was called.*

Comment: That is what I thought I said.

Comment: @SteveMitcham I think the key is that "are not thread safe" - not entirely correct. They are safe but not provide operation over some consistent state.

Comment: *you can see that the enumerator that is returned is not thread safe* It depends on what you mean with thread safe. It won't corrupt data. But it can return "false" results... But then, when the method returns, the result could be falsified by other threads, so the difference is minimal.

Comment: I mean what you meant, but you said it much more clearly than me.

Comment: @xanatos Edited to clarify the meaning of thread safe and link in the documentation from your comment.

Comment: `GetEnumerator` won't be called these days, so the difference is much less than it might have been in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78187070/23354

Answer (score 2):

You will have to benchmark them, because the `Any()` is something like

```
using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

so it requires enumeration, that for `ConcurrentDictionary` is something complex, but even the `Count` of `ConcurrentDictionary` isn't cached and it seems to be pretty complex.

I'll add that the `Count` must still traverse some internal structures (as in an array of) aquiring a lock on the whole dictionary, while the `Any()` will stop at the first non-empty bucket. I'll say that for a big dictionary, `Count` is slower, while for a small one it is faster.

Correction: the `Count` aquires a lock on all the dictionary before counting. it does call `this.AcquireAllLocks()`.

Remember that the result of both method could be falsified before the methods return, because hey... concurrency! :-)

Comment: Did you check the sources or was it's an incredibly precise guess? Just in case: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1425

Comment: @zerkms A third one... ILSpy... Still nearly equivalent to the first one.

Comment: this is no longer the case; `Any` will access `.Count` internally; https://stackoverflow.com/a/78187070/23354

Answer (score 1):

The [current implementation of LINQ](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c622e4322f8c8d6c9988d4141d3050cb99fa75bd/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs#L18-L20) has a number of checks on the input; for example, it checks:

```cs
if (source is ICollection<TSource> gc)
{
    return gc.Count != 0;
}
```

before falling back to other options. Since `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` satisfies this test, *functionally* you'll be using a `.Count` test either way - just with a type test in-between. So it won't make a *huge* difference. If it is a critical code path, maybe do the `.Count` test yourself; otherwise, use whichever is clearer to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

> does it matter whether I use the `Count` property or LINQ's `Any()`

No. They are functionally the same and should have very little performance difference.  Use whatever conveys the meaning most appropriately and only change it if there is a performance problem significant to the performance of the entire application.

`Count` will count the items in the dictionary at the moment that the property is called.

`Any` will call `ConcurrentDictionary.GenEnumerator()` to see if the dictionary has any items.  According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287131(v=vs.110).aspx), the enumerator returned will reflect and changes made to the dictionary after `GetEnumerator()` is called.

So it it theoretically possible that they count get different answers if an item was added between the time that `Any` is called and `MoveNext` is called within `Any`.  However that time window should be so short the likelyhood should be very small.

Plus who's to say which is correct?  If you can `Any` and `Count` at *exactly the same time* that an item is added, is the collection empty or not?

Comment: "However that time window should be so short the likelyhood should be very small" - you've obviously never written any working concurrent code. This para should read "that time window should be so short the likelyhood should only happen several times a day".

Comment: "Any will call ConcurrentDictionary.GenEnumerator()" - I don't know whether this was true at the time of writing, but it isn't true today; https://stackoverflow.com/a/78187070/23354